# How to print out section of dictionary

Tags: list, csv, dictionary, import

My school gave me this code and csv file (not included here) to "explore". In the process of exploring this, I found a few things that I wanted to ask around about. One, below my code is the printout for this program when I run it. If you notice, there is a blank LIST that starts right after the import statements. Yet the printout for the program appears to be in dictionary format, with key and pair values. I am still trying to figure out the differences between the two. I assume that the way the program is showing the data has to do with the fact that it's importing a comma separated value file. But I am still at the point where I don't fully understand how everything works together to get the final result. To summarize, I want to understand the how and why of a blank list printing out like a dictionary in this instance.

The second thing I wanted to ask about was the correct method for printing the whole list of "Name" values only. This applies to any of the keys really, because if I just print out "data" without any restrictions, it's a giant,-system crashing blob of data that keeps trying to load for 10 minutes straight. So I wanted to incorporate in the loop to print out each "Name" value for each index spot. So something like "print(data[counter]["Name"])", with an incrementing counter variable that goes up one index after every print out. But when I tried to do that myself, I could not get it to work. The commented code at the bottom is just examples the school put in there, but that's what results in the printout I posted.

```
import csv
import re
data = []

with open('customerData.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

print(data[0])
print(data[1]["Name"])
print(data[2]["Spent Past 30 Days"])
```

**Output:**

```
{'Member Date': '26/2/2012', 'Zip': '61309', 'Purchases Past 30 Days': '2', 'SSN': '544-48-7885', 'Purchases Past 12 Months': '8', 'Spent Past 12 Months': '$6030.52', 'State': 'WV', 'Spent Past 30 Days': '$943.9000000000001', 'Phone': '(581) 372-8004', 'Gender': 'male', 'Name': 'Steve Bryan', 'Email': 's.Bryan@ru.gov', 'Favorite Radio Station': 'WATT', 'Credit Card_Number': '3491xxxxxxx1481', 'Spent Past 6 Months': '$2099.83', 'Credit Card': 'American Express', 'Credit Card Exp': '02/17', 'Purchases Past 6 Months': '3'}
Dr. Adam Taylor
$3797.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` returns each row of the CSV file as a dictionary with keys that are the column headers from the first line of the CSV and values equal to the columns of the row.

These dictionaries are appended to the `data` list, so what you have is a list of dictionaries.

`data[0]` will return the first dictionary of the list.
`data[1]['Name']` will return the value in the `Name` column for the second data row in the CSV.

Comment: That's good to know. I hadn't noticed that method previously, and I've never been exposed to it before so this is new for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Toph You’re welcome. If the answer is useful consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: Yeah I was gonna wait to see about an answer to part II but you did great and I can split that off into another post. Thanks